# Techniques to find dark matter

Tags: dark-matter

What are recent research techniques to find Dark matter? As they don't interact with other matters, which properties of it can help us to detect it?

Comment: Hi Tarit, I think you'll find that both your questions are discussed extensively in the [Wikipedia article on dark matter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dark_matter). Otherwise, you can always ask on specific topics here, but on this site people are expected to have tried to find the answer themselves first.

Comment: It interacts gravitationally and probably also weakly.